# Search query for JSON data by url

Tags: json, url

I'm using the following url for my JSON data.

```
myapp/laravelRoute/jsondata
```

when entering this in address bar, following JSON array will be displayed

```
[{"A":"B"},{"B":1},{"C","http"}]
```

But, when I enter the url as,

```
myapp/laravelRoute/jsondata?search=B
```

it shows the entire array instead showing the search result. How I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing the code view I found that the array route is configured for a default route in Laravel Routes. So, in any case that open a path except mentioned ones in routes will redirect to the default path.